# show action not working in nested show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out nor know how to google.

Let me explain what the error is before going into the code stuff.

I have an album, which has many photos (photos belong to album).

Album works fine. Photo works fine.

When I try to click on show link of photo ... that's where things seem to go sideways, ie, none of it works after the first one.

Any ideas? Please let me know if further information is needed.

The problem seems to be coming from my Photos controller of show action, ie this:

```
# app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
def show 
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @photo = @album.photos.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

The error that is being generated is this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PhotosController#show 
Couldn't find Album with 'id'=4
```

The weird part is that the first photo of ablum works. It's all other subsequent photos that don't work.

This this the `app/views/photos/show.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Album Details</h1>

<b><p>Title</p></b>
<p><%= @album.title %></p>

<b><p>Descriptions</p></b>
<p><%= @album.description %></p>

<%= link_to "All Albums", albums_path %>

<h3>Photos</h3>
<% @album.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <p>
    <b>Title</b>
    <%= photo.title %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', album_photo_path(photo) %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<h3>Add More Photos</h3>
<%= form_for([@album, @album.photos.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: "When I try to click on show link of photo", can you add that code, the params?

Comment: What are the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you link_to for showing the photo is missing the id for the album.

Instead of

```
<%= link_to 'Show', album_photo_path(photo) %>
```

Should it be

```
<%= link_to 'Show', album_photo_path(@album, photo) %>
```

Since it looks like :album_id is expected as a separate parameter from the photos :id.

Comment: just saw your answer and tried it now. It worked. Thank you. Would you mind explaining this `(@album, photo)` a bit more if you can? I have a huge weakness when it comes to associations, and the code for it ..

Comment: @user273072545345 No problem, I had to go through it too.  Basically, because you have the photo nested in album then the url will be something like **/albums/1/photos/2**.  In order for Rails to know the **id** to use for **album** "1" you have to pass the album object into the link helper.  So what is really happening when you pass **(@album, photo)**  The link helper is seeing **(album_id: 1, id: 2)** so it builds the link /albums/ **:album_id** /photos/ **:id**